# AHK: How to read text from a Pop-up window/Dialog Box?

Tags: scripting, hotkeys, autohotkey

I would like to read the text of a Dialog Box/ Pop-up window and then compare the text of that window to some value. Based on the comparison, I would like to take some action.

Is there a way to read the text of a Dialog Box/ Pop-up window, using AHK scripts?

Thanks
Sunny

Comment: Since no one responded, here are two options. 1. Have you tried "window spy" to see if the data you are looking for is available there? and 2. Have you tried to just use Ctrl+c to copy the content? In some cases Ctrl+c will copy all the text. Otherwise, you can use the first method with e.g. settitlematchmode and Detecthiddentext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Robert said, on some messagebox dialogs you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy its contents to the clipboard.

Otherwise you can use the [WinGetText command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetText.htm) like so:

```
WinGetText, output, My Window's Title
msgbox The text in the window is:`n%output%
```